# Why php handler not sending emails (site running on Nginx server)

Tags: javascript, php, html, nginx, centos7

I have a cloud hosting service account, where I have created a centos 7 vm, and I'm using Nginx as my server. I have been wrestling with the following pieces of a template contact form I found on the internet, trying to build my knowledge with client/server interactions and capturing form data. I was getting errors, but I have debugged most of them. Currently, the behavior:

1. Enter URI of site hosting a form that requires: Name, Email, Message.
2. When that information is submitted, a post successful message displays.

Expected Result:
Message sent to the email configured in the settings.

Actual Result:
Email Message is not sent.

Any direction is appreciated, I've been stumped for almost two days, and at this point probably overlooking something obvious.

Here are the significant pieces of the files I'm working with:

main.js, main.css, index.html, handler.php (placed inside html for this post):

```
...
```

```js
$(function() {
  function after_form_submitted(data) {
    if (data.result == 'success') {
      $('form#reused_form').hide();
      $('#success_message').show();
      $('#error_message').hide();
    } else {
      $('#error_message').append('<ul></ul>');

      jQuery.each(data.errors, function(key, val) {
        $('#error_message ul').append('<li>' + key + ':' + val + '</li>');
      });
      $('#success_message').hide();
      $('#error_message').show();

      //reverse the response on the button
      $('button[type="button"]', $form).each(function() {
        $btn = $(this);
        label = $btn.prop('orig_label');
        if (label) {
          $btn.prop('type', 'submit');
          $btn.text(label);
          $btn.prop('orig_label', '');
        }
      });

    } //else
  }

  $('#reused_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $form = $(this);
    //show some response on the button
    $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function() {
      $btn = $(this);
      $btn.prop('type', 'button');
      $btn.prop('orig_label', $btn.text());
      $btn.text('Sending ...');
    });


    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'handler.php',
      data: $form.serialize(),
      success: after_form_submitted,
      dataType: 'json'
    });

  });
});
```

```css
#form_container {
  background-image: url("images/paper-1914901_1280.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

body {
  background-color: #F4EAD5;
}

#form_container input[type='text'],
#form_container input[type='email'],
#form_container textarea {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Complete Contact Form Using HTML, CSS, Javascript And PHP - reusable form</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
  <script src="form.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="form_container">
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
        <p> Please send your message below. We will get back to you at the earliest! </p>
        <form role="form" method="post" id="reused_form">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
              <label for="message"> Message:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="message" name="message" maxlength="6000" rows="7"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
              <label for="name"> Your Name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
              <label for="email"> Email:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default pull-right">Send &rarr;</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div id="success_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
          <h3>Posted your message successfully!</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
          <h3>Error</h3> Sorry there was an error sending your form. </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )

 */
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['name','email'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('message')->maxLength(6000);




$pp->sendEmailTo('someone@gmail.com'); // ← Your email here

echo $pp->process($_POST);

?>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start sending mail, then things get tricky simply because email server config is tricky.  Is your server set up so that you can send mail as a regular user from the shell? Ie `mail -s test someuser@gmail.com`  (hit enter, type a message, hit enter a few times, hit ctrl+d and off it goes).  If mail is not set up properly, it may not leave the machine, or if it does, it may not be accepted by the receiving server.

Once you know the mail server part works, then you can worry about sending mail with PHP.  Something like this Just Works to send a plain text email BUT the mail server must be configured properly.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])){

        $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: no-reply <no-reply@example.com>\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: no-reply <no-reply@example.com>\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: php-form2mail";

        $subject="Form submission";

        $message_body=
        "   Hello, this a message generated by a form submission.

        Be sure to wrap your lines at about 70 characters, just so it
        looks nice on peoples mail clients.  If you have a link the mail
        client will almost always make a plain URL clickable - test it

        http://www.google.com


        Here's what the form contained:
        ";

        foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){
            $message_body .= "\n".$k." : $v \n";
        }

        mail($to_address, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

        print("<h2>Thank you</h2>");
        print("<strong>You told us:</strong><br />");
        foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){
            print("\n<br />".$k." : $v <br />\n";
        }
    }
?>
```